# Application Development Using WSO2 Servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Can I have source code of any running application/Test case build using (DSS,ESB,IS,AS, etc).

I am able to understand the these servers separately but not able to deliver any project using these servers collectively.

Do not have clue to use all these servers collectively best way and din't get any video, article or samples using all there in one application.

I Have already posted this question in StackOverflow, but din't get any response.

Please help me to achieve the same so that the greatness of WSO2, I can show to some of my colleague and We can go long with WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Retail Bankning Sample with WSO2 Developer Studio and bunch of other WSO2 Servers such as WSO2 ESB, WSO2 BPS, WSO2 DSS, WSO2 AS etc [1]. This sample was demonstrated on this webinar as well [2]. Source code for the Webinar is in [3].

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Retail+Banking+Sample

[2]. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hdq1Qq-XSc

[3]. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/tools/ide/eclipse/docs/src/main/resources/samples/banking-sample/Webinar/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Harshana, I want a single login page where user can be created, deleted, can be given role, and the human task can be sent to these created user, and task will been approved/reject by these created user. How to bring the inbox of BPS to my UIs(HTML). All these server work as backend only and I can design UI for single sign on and all user can login and access the application. Here access of application means, One should be able to trigger the BPM, One should be able to claim the task (Via BPS INBOX), One should be able to do CRUD operation on DSS. Please help, It will be very greatfull.